# bootstrap: col-xs-6 are displayed in width 100% in a mobile view

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I am using bootstrap
I want to split a row in 2 columns when I display a mobile view
I have the code bellow:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
   

    <title>test mobile</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-8 ">col-xs-6 col-sm-8</div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 ">col-xs-6 col-sm-4</div>
      </div>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

it display correctly the md view but in mobile view columns take the full line space instead of taking half the width
[image]

Do you know what happens and how to solve it please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using the latest version of Bootstrap I think they have [removed the **xs** class](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/). Just use **col-6** instead of **col-xs-6** and you should be fine.